# Can't figure out how to return a string composed of two variables, a string and a integer?- repost, updated

Tags: java

This program is using a get/set method for both, but I just can't  figure out how!

Thanks to a helpful user recommending string.valueOf, I now have this

```java
public int getSeatNumber() {
    String output = "" + seatLetter + String.valueOf(seatNumber);
    return output;
}
```

but it still has the same error,

> "Incompatible types, string cannot be converted to an int".

Here is the full object, although not all variables are set, as this is recycled code.

```java
public class Ticket {

    private int seatNumber, phoneNumber;
    private double price;
    private String seatLetter, name;

    //default constructor
    public Ticket() {
        price = 300;
        seatNumber = 1;
        name = "John Doe";
        seatLetter = "A";
        
    }
    public double getPrice() {
      return price;
    }

    public int getSeatNumber() {
        String output = "" + seatLetter + String.valueOf(seatNumber);
        return output;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setPrice(double _price) {
        price = _price;
    }

    public void setSeatNumber(int _seatNumber) {
        seatNumber = _seatNumber;
    }

    public void setSeatName(String _seatLetter) {
        seatLetter = _seatLetter;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String output = "";
        output += "Model = " + model + "\n";
        output += "Price = $" + price + "\n";
        output += "Horsepower = " + horsePower + "HP";
        return output;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to return a value like "A1", the return type must be `String`, not `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You've declared a data type of String output and returning a string when the method is completed, but if you take a closer look at your method declaration, it is declaring that your method will return an int.

- `public int getSeatNumber()` <-- need to return an int type.
- `public String getSeatNumber()` should work without throwing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method to this:

```
public String getSeatNumber() {

    String output = "" + seatLetter + String.valueOf(seatNumber);

    return output; 
}
```

Notice how I changed the method return type to `String`.

I advice you use `String.format` instead, as it will make your code cleaner (I didn't use it since I don't know the types of your values).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).